# What type of encryption is this?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I have recovered a decryption algorithm from the binary. However, I do not understand if this is a "custom" or some kind of public key encryption.
Could you please give me a hint what might it be?

```
def mul_mod(K, M, n):
    return (K * M % n)

A = 0x0807FE482C385ACA9A13F78CA4926C5E782F8C7361AE1BA8596BC5386ADFA360CA0834CACB149028C1EC031EF6C7A2D0BA4E4EF6DE12CA67B34C17B7DD65F487BF99C20B9FE9D49782B03D9FDC2DB4CC6AE07A1ED01F0EF4CE7445EB4512518C0F12ED3A19D9CD48D36A2D67DF5F9B5AC9FAEA0E6F61255304BF26DA77FD31DE
n = 0xD0BD213EA460B9B9E16E169B1664D15BD83EB626B1C1711AA062B553BDD8C1A57B9A416E5AADD91DF5D41BA95FE6F65AA700F47FD1BCDE231A774B6E6EE1ACAC820894ABDBD2F0D3805F93948FFF716030E63460B8C30A2FF7589616CDB3550ABF34ADF16DD0281477F8B4111B1CCAB00583B4C97C2FCBA72DF607EEE3BCF561
C = 0x10001
LEN = 0x20

c = C
l = LEN
while not (c & 0xC0000000):
    c *= 4
    l -= 2

if l:
    left = ((l-1) >> 1) + 1
    res = 1

    while left:
        res = mul_mod(res, res, n)
        res = mul_mod(res, res, n)

        if c >> 0x1E:
            res = mul_mod(res, A, n)

        c = (c << 2) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        left -= 1

print("Decrypted (plain): " + hex(res))
```

Decrypted payload:

```
0019F7EC A9 12 CE 9D F7 C5 6A 6C E9 4C 53 B0 6B E8 A8 99 ©.Î.÷ÅjléLS°kè¨. 
0019F7FC 22 A4 33 04 AE 3D DF BE 20 F9 21 D9 8C 6C 93 21 "¤3.®=ß¾ ù!Ù.l.! 
0019F80C 57 A5 ED 03 C4 25 38 7D F9 7D F1 8F 69 5A 00 ED W¥í.Ä%8}ù}ñ.iZ.í 
0019F81C 4F DB 8E 3F 39 E4 0C A4 7D E9 7A 94 00 00 01 C3 OÛ.?9ä.¤}éz....Ã 
0019F82C 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF .ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ 
0019F83C FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ 
0019F84C FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ 
0019F85C FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 01 00 ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ..
```

Comment: It's an obfuscated form of RSA signature verification. At least for these particular values it just computes `pow(A, 65537, n)`. The result appears to be similar to a PKCS#1 ver 1.5 block type 1 padded hash, except I'm not really sure what the payload is

Comment: First 0x10 bytes of the payload (in reverse order - 94 7A E9 7D A4 0C E4 39 3F 8E DB 4F ED 00 5A 69) is a key for decrypting text with AES-128. I've also added decrypted result to the question. Thank you for your help!